# Java - Metadata Api readMetadata() not returning corrrect info

Tags: webservices, metadata-api, java

I am trying calling readMetadata() method in java to return all instances of a metadata type in my sandbox: For example calling readMetadata("ApexClass") will return the api names of all apex classes in my org. As you can see, I am attempting to use the "*" wildcard here but that doesn't seem to work.

PS: This method works if I call  `metadataConnection.readMetadata("CustomObject",new String[] { "Account" });`

I want to make it generic enough to be able to just provide the metadata type and get all instances of it.

```
public static void readData(String metadataType) {
    try {
        ReadResult readResult = metadataConnection.readMetadata(metadataType,new String[] { "*" });
        Metadata[] mdInfo = readResult.getRecords();

        for (Metadata md : mdInfo) {
            if (md != null) {
                //parse results into a list
            } else {
                System.out.println("Empty metadata.");
            }
        }
    } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_readMetadata.htm) on `readMetadata()`, it does not seem like wildcard selection is possible, since the limit on returned results is 10.

> #### Arguments
>
> - **Name** `fullNames`
> - **Type** `string[]`
> - **Description** `Array of full names of the components to read.`
>     `Limit: 10. (For CustomMetadata only, the limit is 200.)`
>
>   `You must submit arrays of only one type of component. For example, you can submit an array of 10 custom objects or 10 profiles, but not a mix of both types.`